# how to embeded the c++ coding with tcl script:NS2

Tags: c++, tcl, ns2

how to embeded the c++ coding with tcl script:NS2

Answer (score 2):

You cannot embedded C++ in TCL scripts(to the best of my knowledge, its not allowed). C++ is used to create the backend libraries of ns2 so that your simulator knows how the protocols are supposed to behave.

With the TCL script what you do is basically design a network. Pretty much the same way you would have graphically designed your network on qualnet.

If you would like to define a protocol, its written in C++ and then use it to run your simulations for a network designed in TCL. It is the same way you do it in the existing examples.